# How to explicitly reference core classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm working with Chef, and I have run into a situation where I need to use the Ruby `File.dirname()` class method. Problem is, Chef has it's own `Chef::Resource::File` class which is resolved when executing code within a `ruby_block` resource. How can one explicitly reference the core namespace File class when there is a naming conflict?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prepend the class name with `::`, i.e., `::File`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Chef itself does not overload anything here.  The problem is that you are in a `::Chef::Resource::RubyBlock` and you're attempting to do a symbol lookup on "File".  The Ruby Language searches upwards and finds `::Chef::Resource::File` before it finds `::File`.  The correct solution is to use `::File.dirname` and that is simply a feature (which could not be easily changed without a ton of breakage) of Ruby.

Comment: Overload was probably not the right term to use here. I meant that Chef clearly also had a File class, which File was resolving to instead of the ::File class. I meant "overload" similarly to what it means to use the same name for multiple functions or methods, though I don't know a better term to use when referring to classes that "stomp" on other classes that might be available.

Comment: In either event, thanks for the correction. I've edited the original question to use a different moniker to describe the behavior I was experiencing.